# Client config for WCF - where?

Tags: wcf

I've created a WCF service, configured it in it web.config.

What do people mean when you also have to configure the "client"?  I don't get that, is that another web.config or app.config somewhere?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukadc/archive/2010/04/22/setting-up-wcf-with-a-load-balancer-using-ssl-in-the-middle.aspx "Setting up WCF with a load balancer using SSL in the middle"

Comment: There's a whole book on the thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560536.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client has to have a binding and endpoint where it connects to. Your client is configured, either in app_ or web.config, or you can configure it in code behind.

If your WCF service exposes an endpoint "`X`" on binding (`basicHttpbinding`), your client needs to be configured to connect to service "`X`" using `basicHttpbinding`.

If you use the "Add Service Reference" option in visual studio, and provide your service address, I.e. `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/serviceEndpointAddress` , visual studio will look at it, and build the necessary binding and config for you.

Comment: so I'm asking if the client has to be configured in the web.config of the actual service or in the config of the calling app

Comment: The client gets configured in its "own" web or app config, or as stated, in codebehind (on the client)